# GAE Managed VMs: Possible to use C-based Python libraries with standard runtime?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm building a background module for my app in Python 2.7, but it needs to use C-based external libraries such as OpenCV. While GAE only "directly" supports pure Python libraries, I understand that using a managed VM removes that constraint. What I'm not quite clear on, after reading [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/), is whether I would need to use a custom runtime, or whether a standard Python runtime (for which there's a ready-made Docker file and built-in API support for Datastore, Task Queue, etc.) would be sufficient.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard runtime is fine, you just need to add your extra dependencies to the Dockerfile that gets created. [The tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/tutorial/step1) in the docs (specifically Step 6) shows an example of building a python app that uses a C-extension.

Comment: Thank you! I'd love to vote up your answer, but apparently I can't because I recently joined and don't have enough badges. :(